# alternating page numbers in scrbook

Tags: page-numbering, include, scrbook

I just realized that my document, written with `scrbook` does not have the page numbers on every page, and the behaviour looks very strange to me: My document is mainly made of chapters includes with the `\include` command. The page numbers are not on each page, and they are not alternating either: the number 5, 8, 12 are written, but there is no 6,7,9,10,11.
I also introduced a few bogus `\chapter`; in that case the page number are on all pages. It appears to be a problem due to the `\include` command

Here is my MWE with the entire preamble.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true,oneside,bibliography=leveldown]{scrbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}%per la flowchart
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{caption}  %per aggiungere captions al PRISMA ed evitare il floating delle tavole
\usepackage{booktabs} % For prettier tables
\usepackage{subfig} %per figure multiple


\usepackage{amsmath}%aggiunto per le tabelle dell'appendice
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}%aggiunto per le tabelle dell'appendice


\usepackage[style=vancouver,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, doi=false]{biblatex}

%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pdfpages}%per inserire pdf multipagina
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}%multicolonna
\usepackage{enumitem}%mi serve per gli elenchi semza punto
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}%toglie i riquadri rossi intorno a hyperlinks come toc e citazioni e ne ridefinisce alcuni in blu


% Text styles
\newcommand\textstyleEmphasis[1]{\textit{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
    \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
    \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
    \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
    \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
    \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
%qui finisce l'ultima aggiunta

%per ordinare alfabeticamente le abbreviazioni
\newcommand{\sortitem}[2]{%
    \DTLnewrow{list}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#2}%
}

\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
    \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
}{%
    \DTLsort{label}{list}%
    \begin{description}%
        \DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label,\theDesc=description}{%
            \item[\theLabel] \theDesc }%
    \end{description}%
}

\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
%\setkomafont{element}{commands}
\setkomafont{title}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\addtokomafont{part}{\color{cyan}}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{black}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{cyan}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{cyan}}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\textbf}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\color{cyan}\partname~\thepart}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \scalebox{3}{\color{cyan}\thechapter}%
}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[
tocindent=2em
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
tocindent=4em
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
tocindent=6em
]{subsection}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
        {\chapapp\nobreakspace\thechapter}%
    }
    
}
\makeatother
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
    \subsection*{#1}%ridefinisce l'heading della bibliografia come subsection
    \addxcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}%lo aggiunge alla TOC

\addbibresource{LGBiBiblio.bib}
%\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{}


\begin{document}
    \author{}
    
    \subject{Linea Guida}
    \title{\textbf{Il trattamento laparoscopico di laparocele e ernie ventrali}}
    \subtitle{}
    \titlehead{}
    
    
    \date{Gennaio 2022}
    
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

    
    \mainmatter

    \chapter{one}
    
    text
    
    \chapter{two}
    
    text
    
    \chapter{three}
    
    text
    
    \chapter{four}
    
    text
    
    \include{./capitoli/in_italia}
    \include{./capitoli/scopo}
    \include{./capitoli/definizioni}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is impossible for us to tell, since you are not showing us the included files. The missing page nunbers are probably a result of `\thispagestyle{empty}`, which could be called e.g. by the `\includepdf` command.

Comment: Also your example is far from minimal. Most of the code is not needed to reproduce the problem, so please remove it. By doing this, you will often identify the source of your problem yourself. You cannot expect the people from this site to read all your unnecessary code just to check if there are some commands which might change page numbers.

Comment: @marv You are right, as usual: the problem was linked to this code `\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
 \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
 \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
 \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
 \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
 \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}`